# How do I prevent distutils from adding -I/usr/include/python2.7 to the gcc command line? (or change it to something else)

Tags: python, distutils

I'm crosscompiling my extension with distutils (well, through cffi.setsource, but it passes [these params](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=library_dirs#distutils.core.Extension) directly to distutils.Extension), and need to provide an alternate path for Python headers.

`SYSROOT_TARGET` is a path to my target platform's sysroot.

I have included `SYSROOT_TARGET+'/usr/include/python2.7/'` in include_dirs, **which works fine** as it searches that dir first, but I feel uneasy about this warning that it prints:

> cc1: warning: include location "/usr/include/python2.7" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]

This occurs because it adds `-I/usr/include/python2.7` to the gcc command line just before the `-c` flag.

Is there an envvar I can set to modify or get rid of that argument completely?

`os.environ['PYTHONXCPREFIX'] = SYSROOT_TARGET+'/usr'` doesn't change anything.

I know it does take envvars into account because that's how I set my compiler to the one from my toolchain.

`os.environ['CC'] =  SYSROOT + '/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc'`

To be clear, building like this works just fine (*for now*...), but I would rather not poison my include dirs like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `ffibuilder.emit_c_code()` instead of `ffibuilder.compile()`, then compiling it myself.